# Is it possible to delete id from multitable if available in any one table?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is it possible to delete id from more than one table if available in any one table?
like -

```
"DELETE from EXCEL_ENTRY WHERE ID = '" & id & "' " _    
        & "union DELETE from DRAWING WHERE ID = '" & id & "' " _    
        & "union DELETE from DESIGN WHERE ID = '" & id & "' " _    
        & "union DELETE from ESTIMATE WHERE ID = '" & id & "'"
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE...

Comment: my id is in one of the table and i have displayed all the value using union... but how to delete.. I don't know.. so plz help?

Comment: Any one have the sql query than help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a joined query on basis of same id that relates your table

```
DELETE 
  ee.*,
  dr.*,
  de.*,
  e.* 
FROM
  EXCEL_ENTRY ee
  INNER JOIN DRAWING dr 
    ON (ee.id = dr.id) 
  INNER JOIN DESIGN de 
    ON (ee.id = de.id) 
  INNER JOIN ESTIMATE e 
    ON (ee.id = e.id) 
WHERE ee.ID = 'your_id'
```

But better approach is to do this  define foreign key relations  with cascade delete option, Note you should try above delete query on your sample data first do not use directly on your production database

Comment: I have a more than one table with columns id, name, contact but the id value is do not match with other table.... If id  = 1 is availabe in one table than in rest of the table there is no id with value 1...

Answer (score 0):

What table types are you using? If InnoDB then correct approach would be to have foreign keys in `DRAWING`, `DESIGN` and `ESTIMATE` table to reference the EXCEL_ENTRY. Using `ON DELETE CASCADE` would delete the the matching rows automatically from those tables if you delete the entry from `EXCEL_ENTRY`.

As an example, use the following to add Foreign key reference to `DRAWING`

```
ALTER TABLE DRAWING 
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES EXCEL_ENTRY (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**Update:**

If your `EXCEL_ENTRY` table doesn't have `ID` indexed, then you need to add that first:

```
ALTER TABLE EXCEL_ENTRY ADD INDEX (id);
```

Comment: this code is not working... it show the msg - error in your sql syntax.

Comment: First add the index to `EXCEL_ENTRY` and then add the Foreign Key to `DRAWING`. What's the MySQL version you are using and error message you get?

Comment: MySql Version - 5.5.24  and I am getting the sql syntax error